# Nokogiri #parse_memory method

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a legacy code like the following:

```
myxml = some xml data
parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(somedoc)
parser.parse_memory myxml
```

What is `parse_memory`? What does it do?

Comment: Here is the documentation for the class. http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/HTML/SAX/Parser.html

Comment: @depa OP might be looking for the functionality,why we use this method.. Frankly speaking the doc is saying that the method only exist..not more than that. Nokogiri didn't document some of its methods very well..

Comment: My guess is that it calculates the minimum memory required for a SAX parser as it depends on the depth of the XML file.

Comment: Yes. I posted the link as a comment rather than an answer for that very same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `parse_memory` method parses an XML document that is stored in memory, as opposed to a document that is stored on the filesystem, or behind an `IO` instance.